# Why K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0] return “None” wiht Kears CNN？

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a network structure like this

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 7507, 2131)        15999548  
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 7507, 256)         2727936   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 2503, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 256)               525312    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4096)              1052672   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2131)              8730707   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 2131)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 29,036,175
Trainable params: 29,036,175
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Then I want to calculate gradient information for the given input，like this

```
adv_list = []
loss = layer_list[-2][1].output[:, f]
grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]
iterate = K.function([model.input], [loss, grads])
```

However, when the code execute to this line:
`grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]`
I found it returns nothing but None object, so the program fail to progress after that.
And grads is None, I printed some intermediate information

```
('loss: ', <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>)
('model.input', <tf.Tensor 'embedding_1_input:0' shape=(?, 7507) dtype=float32>)
('K.gradients(loss, model.input', [None])
```

Comment: what is the loss function?

Comment: Loss is to select the neurons in the output layer，like this

Comment: ` ('layer_list[-2][1].output: ', <tf.Tensor 'dense_2/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 2123) dtype=float32>) `